# No funciona el colspan en el Datatable en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables, razor

Por ejemplo, tengo un datatable:

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table_1').DataTable( );
});

 </script>
<table id="table_1" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
<thead>

    <tr style="background-color: #ff6a00; color: #fff">
        <th>Dato 1</th>
        <th>Dato 2</th>
        <th>Dato 3</th>
        <th>Dato 4</th>

    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td colspan="3"></td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Pero al usar el colspan, pierdo la propiedad del filtro, paginación y buscador del datatable. Me doy cuenta que no trabaja, o hay algo incompatible en su uso. Me gustaría poder encontrar una solución. Alguien sabe como llegar a usar el colspan en el datatable???

Actualmente hay una solución, por ejemplo:

```
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3">Wide column</td>
  <td style="display: none;"></td>
  <td style="display: none;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Normal column</td>
 <td>Normal column</td>
 <td>Normal column</td>
</tr>
```

Pero no disminuye el width de la celda que se oculta. Se ve mal, aunque le ponga width =0. Me queda la tabla alineada a la izquierda con los anchos sobrantes a la derecha. No se ve bien

Comment: Puede ser un problema de como llenas el datatable, mas que de lo que haces con las columnas?

Answer (score 1):

Excelente, pude emular con css: la solucion seria esto:

```
  position:absolute;margin-left: 0; display: inline-block;"
```

esto hace que se me vea bien sin afectar el ancho de las celdas

Comment: ¿Puedes poner una imagen del grid para ver que es lo que querías hacer?

He visto que para esos casos recomiendan: https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/row_details.html, pero no se cual era tu necesidad en sí, o mas bien el resultado al que querías llegar.

Answer (score 0):

Aun no hay soporte con databales.

> Sorry - at the moment Responsive does not work with colspan. This is a
>   known limitation that I hope to get time to resolve with a future
>   release.

[Fuente](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/35753/rendering-errors-when-using-responsive-and-th-with-colspan)

Comment: pero habra algun metodo de emular, por ejemplo colocar algun div adentro o hacer algo con css?